# Calculating statistics for a series of discrete random variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, generating-functions

Usual disclaimer: I'm a software engineer trying to use mathematics to solve a problem. I only have a shallow understanding of these things. My terminology will probably be wrong. Please be gentle.

I know how to work with a single discrete random variable $X$ with alphabet of outcomes $\mathcal{X}$, but what I have is, you might say, a formula (algorithm) for generating $X_k$, where $k = |\mathcal{X}|$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. What I want to calculate is, for example, expected value, $E(X)$, and entropy, $H(X)$. But I want to calculate them, how do you say, at the limit, for $X_{\infty}$.

Is this multivariate probability or something different, given that each $X_k$ is modelling the same thing, and so in a sense is the same variable, but at a larger size?

Can I find some definition of $X_\infty$, I don't know, using a generating function, from which I can then directly calculate $E(X_\infty)$, $H(X_\infty)$, etc, or should I be calculating the limit of each statistic separately?

If I could define $X_{k}$ in terms of $X_{k-1}$, would that help?

Also, is there a CAS that can model this $X_\infty$, or a recurrence relation of $X$ as I mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah-oh. Unfortunately your terminology and definitions are a bit incomprehensible as written (for stupid me, at least), so let's start from the beginning. I presume that $f$ is a function of 3 integer variables returning a non-negative integer. Now, what is $C$, is $C^k$ "C to the power k" or "C superscript k" and what does the notation $E_0=\{\varepsilon=C^0\}$ mean?

Comment: @fedja, thanks for inquiring.
For the sake of argument, yes, let's say that $f$ is a function on three integer variables, and it could be as trivial as $C^{n-1} - C^k$.
$C$ is a non-negative integer, so yes, $C^k$ is "$C$ to the power of $k$".
I used $E_0$ in the same sense as I see $a_n$ used for a series, but I used $E$ to emphasize that it's an event space. So $\epsilon$ is one possible outcome, as are $x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}$. There are $C^n$ events and so those events must be distributed across the possible outcomes, which is essentially determined by $f$.

Comment: On reflection, I'm going to overhaul this question and recast it in terms of a discrete random variable. It will remove some of the unnecessary detail and get straight to the point.

Comment: What is $k=|X|$?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis The size of the DRV's alphabet. Sorry, should be a different symbol, I'll edit, thanks.